# При вводе нескольких строк через for теряется первый символ, начиная со второй строки

Tags: c++, c

```
int main() {
    string s;
    int n;
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Введите ваше имя: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, s);
        cout << "Ваше имя: " << s << endl;
        s = "";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

При вводе первой строки выводит нормально, но начиная со второго ввода теряется первый символ, объясните, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: `cin.ignore();` должен вызываться один раз  перед циклом

Comment: 1) `cin >> n;` число считано, символ новой строки остался во входном потоке. 2) На нулевой итерации цикла `cin.ignore();` "съедает " символ новой строки. 3) `getline` в отличие от `cin >> n;` символ новой строки во входном потоке **не** оставляет, поэтому на всех последующих итерациях `cin.ignore();` "съедает" первый символ (перевода строки -то нет, `getline` с прошлой итерации ничего не оставил во входном потоке).